# Android Studio update activity at 'Run'

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio, android-activity

At first, I'm new in programming of Android. And I have a problem/question.
Every Time i will click the 'Run' button to build and run my application on my device, my changes in the activity doesn't update/apply on device.

Is Anybody the, who know what i mean and know how to fix my problem.

I tried to find something in the preferences but i haven't found something.
At the moment i have to rebuild every time before run but this isn't a very nice way i think. There should be a better one.


Thank you for your answers.


Greetings

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project. Try to restart the Emulator and Android Studio.

Comment: that means, i have to do this before every Run? @Vucko

Comment: No. Guess this is some kind of a bug. Did it work?

Comment: Yes, but i think it is a bit ornate to do it every Time @Vucko

Comment: Try to change something and run again. If it still works, I'll migrate my comment to the answer and you might accept it.

Comment: @Vucko If i accept an answer than it is the one of "Enzokie" because he answered first.... But i think it isn't the best solution, Sorry

Comment: Sure. I'm certain that you do not need to do this every time. Reinstall Android Studio if it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Instant Run, this is probably whats causing the problem - it doesnt recognise the changes you've made (at least that was the cause when I first had this problem). Just rebuild or clean your Project as already suggested - this will cause Instant Run to fully reinstall your application and not only install the new Patches. For me it occurrs quite often, I don't really see a pattern behind it but it's usually when I go to edit a completely different file/class, or when starting a new programming session.

Answer (score 1):

Goto **Build > Rebuild Project** after that click **Run** again.

If it does not still updates your app I suggest to uninstall the app on the phone or in your emulator then **Run** again so a that a fresh APK copy will be installed.

Note: This is an odd thing when you are just running again without changing anything in your code.

Comment: that means, i have to do this before every Run?

Comment: Not really, use only this steps if it does not updates your app upon running. Android Studio isn't perfect, there are still unknown bugs lingering within it.

Answer (score 1):

The content should change, but I've noticed that with the latest instant run method, asset files typically don't get updated when you run it again. You could try setting up your preferences again and making sure you have updated your gradle, but if it's not updating you can simply kill the app before you run it again, either with the red stop button on Android Studio or though your phone.